# How can I remove all trailing backslashes from a string in Scala?

Tags: regex, scala

I want to remove all trailing backslashes (`'\'`) from a string.

For example:

```
"ab"       -> "ab" 
"ab\\\\"   -> "ab"
"\\\\ab\\" -> "\\\\ab"
"\\"       -> ""
```

I am able to do this using below code but unable to handle the scenario where the String has only slash(es). Please let me know if this can be achieved through a different regex.

```
val str = """\\\\q\\"""
val regex = """^(.*[^\\])(\\+)$""".r
str match  {
  case regex(rest, slashes) => str.stripSuffix(slashes)
  case _ => str
}
```

Comment: Try: `str.replaceFirst("\\\\+$", "");`

Comment: Maybe add this as an answer ? Seems great :-)

Comment: @anubhava, it works. Guess you don't need any more rep:)

Comment: Better use `str.replaceFirst("""\\+$""", "");`, no need overescaping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting my comment as an answer. This should work for removing all trailing backslashes:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("\\\\+$", "");
```

`\\\\+` matches 1+ backslashes (single backslash is entered as `\\\\` in Java/Scala).

Answer (score 2):

While not a regex, I suggest a simpler solution : `str.reverse.dropWhile(_ == '\\').reverse`

Comment: Unclosed literal character... Backslashes! Backslashes! That's why it's so fun! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not using a regex, but you could use [`String.lastIndexWhere(p: (Char) ⇒ Boolean)`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#lastIndexWhere(p:A=%3EBoolean):Int) to get the position of the last character which is not a `'\'` in order to substring until this character:

```
str.substring(0, str.lastIndexWhere(_ != '\\') + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If, for some reason, you're committed to a regex solution, it can be done.

```
val regex = """[^\\]?(\\*)$""".r.unanchored
str match  {
  case regex(slashes) => str.stripSuffix(slashes)
}
```

Comment: seems i was complicating the solution to a simple question, but thanks for bending it my way. Can i ask why `"""\\+$""".r.unachored` when replaced in your answer doesn't work?

Comment: The `+` means "one-or-more" so a string without a backslash won't match. The `*`, zero-or-more, will always make a capture. If there are no backslashes then the capture is empty, but still valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with `slice` function

```
str.slice(0,str.lastIndexWhere(_ != '\\')+1)
```

Comment: Yes, He should comment.